# How to use update panel in datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Below is the code which i have applied, it is giving me a error.

```
 <asp:TemplateColumn>
           <HeaderTemplate >
           <label>Article</label>
               </HeaderTemplate>       
              <ItemTemplate>      
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpArticle" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged = "DrpArticle_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems = "true">      
                        </asp:DropDownList>                                  
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DrpArticle" EventName="OnSelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LblStock" runat="server" Text="..." ForeColor="#000066"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
              </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Do not use UpdatePanel inside the DataGrid. Wrap the entire DataGrid with one UpdatePanel.